# How to create an automatic index

Tags: python

How can I generate this pattern automatically?

```
indice = ["A Minus 2", "A Plus 2", "A Minus 3", "A Plus 3", "A Minus 4", "A Plus 4", "A Minus 5", "A Plus 5"]
```

It's fast just to write down this list, but I imagine it can be hard if that pattern goes on.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. We expect that you make a good faith effort at answering the question first. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I think OP is asking because they don't know a better way to do it than to write each combination out manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
indice = []
for i in range(num):
    indice.append(f'A Plus {i}')
    indice.append(f'A Minus {i}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a nested generator expression:

```
>>> [f"A {op} {num}" for num in range(2, 6) for op in ("Minus", "Plus")]
['A Minus 2', 'A Plus 2', 'A Minus 3', 'A Plus 3', 'A Minus 4', 'A Plus 4', 'A Minus 5', 'A Plus 5']
```

This approach easily scales out to more operations (e.g. adding "Times"), or adding more variables (`for var in "ABCDE"`), etc.

An equivalent option is to use `itertools.product`, which gives you all the possible combinations of an arbitrary list of iterables:

```
>>> [f"A {op} {num}" for op, num in itertools.product(("Minus", "Plus"), range(2, 6))]
['A Minus 2', 'A Minus 3', 'A Minus 4', 'A Minus 5', 'A Plus 2', 'A Plus 3', 'A Plus 4', 'A Plus 5']
```